# WordPress set featured image to first image of the post

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails, actions

I have tried every solution from similar answers and nothing seems to work on Wordpress 5.0 +

When saving a post I want to set its featured image to the first image in the post content.

```
function auto_set_featured( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  $images = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent'    => $post_id,
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  ) );

  set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $images[0]->ID );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_set_featured', 10, 3);
```

In `set_post_thumbnail()` if I set the image id manually it works but it does not seem to pick up `$images[0]->ID` I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Note: I'm testing on posts which have multiple images in the content so `$images` should be returning an array. I also tried using `$post->ID` and `get_the_ID()` in the query and it does not work. I also tried adding the post ID manually for `post_parent`.

Comment: what do you get? any errors?

Comment: do a `var_dump($images)` before `set_post_thumbnail` and see what you get.

Comment: @AlexanderHolsgrove it gives `array(0) { }` so i'm not sure why it is not returning any images. The query seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already used this image in a different post? The `post_parent` may already be assigned to a different post ID from the one you are on. The code you have will only return images uploaded to this post first.

I've seen a few regex type solutions to this problem, however I think [PHPs DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) may be safer. This is also very experimental but seems to work for me:

```
function auto_set_featured($post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($post->post_content, LIBXML_NOWARNING);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    if($images->length > 0) {
        $first_image = $images->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
        $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid($first_image);
        if($attachment_id) {
            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Should be simple enough to follow, but it loads the post content, and looks for the first `img` DOMElement. We then use that image URL with [attachment_url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/) to get the attachment ID, which you pass to set_post_thumbnail as per your code.

Comment: This does not seem to work

Comment: Where does it fail? Can you add `var_dump($images)` and tell me the output?